# django - iterate through model in create view & return inline formset

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a formset that will allow the user to set scores for each `Priority` when creating a new project with the `CreateView`. The `Priority` model already has data associated (3 values) foreach `Priority` that has been created I'm trying to return a char-field in the `Project` `CreateView` where the user can enter the `score` for the `Priority`.

Currently I have the three char-fields showing up in the `Project` `CreateView` but the priority isn't being saved. I have done some testing & it looks like the `ProjectPriority` is never having the `Project` or `Priority` values set only the score value.

I have been struggling for days trying to get this to work. I appreciate all the help.

**Views.py**

```py
class ProjectCreateview(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectCreationForm
    success_url = 'home/project/project_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ChildFormset = inlineformset_factory(
            Project, ProjectPriority, fields=('priority', 'score'), can_delete=False, extra=Priority.objects.count(),
        )
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['priorities'] = ChildFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data['priorities'] = ChildFormset(instance=self.object)
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        priorities = context["priorities"]
        self.object = form.save()
        if priorities.is_valid():
            priorities.instance = self.object
            priorities.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**Models.py**

```
class Priority(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Title", max_length=250)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.title

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Project Title", max_length=100)
    details = models.TextField(verbose_name="Project Details/Description", blank=False)
    priority = models.ManyToManyField(
        Priority,
        through='ProjectPriority',
        related_name='priority'
    )
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ProjectPriority(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority = models.ForeignKey(Priority, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.CharField(max_length=1000, choices=priority_choices)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Priority"
        verbose_name_plural = "Priorities"

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Priority: {self.priority.title}, Score: {self.score}, Project: {self.project.name}"
```

**Template**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 25px;">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-8">
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">New Project</legend>
        {{ form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>

    <h2>Priority Criteria</h2>
    {{ priorities|crispy }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create 
Project</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You have set `fields=('score',)` on the inline formset, how do you expect the foreign key `priority` to be set to the form? Try `fields=('priority', 'score')` instead...

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Setting `fields=('priority', 'score')` didn't work. It got rid of the error but the `Priority` is still not being save with the `Project`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `form_valid` method you have code like so:

```py
def form_valid(self, form):
    context = self.get_context_data()
    priorities = context["priorities"]
    self.object = form.save()
    if priorities.is_valid():
        priorities.instance = self.object
        priorities.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

But trying to set the instance at this point (after calling `is_valid`) will not work because the forms have already been constructed when you call `priorities.is_valid()` which loops over the cached property `forms` of the formset which causes the forms to be constructed with the `instance` then being set to an empty one (because you didn't provide it yet). The solution would be simply to set the instance before calling `is_valid`. Also note the `super().form_valid(form)` will also save the object, you should instead return the response yourself there:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


class ProjectCreateview(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    # Other attributes and get_context_data here
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        priorities = context["priorities"]
        self.object = form.save()
        priorities.instance = self.object # Set the instance here
        if priorities.is_valid():
            priorities.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Comment: I tried this and I'm not getting any errors but when I try to use use `{{ project.priority }}` it's returning `home.Priority.None`. I figure it's still not saving correctly? (the rest of the project data returns fine)

Comment: @GaryHost `priority` is a `ManyToManyField` on the model `Project` which means `project.priority` will give you the related manager. Try writing `{% for priority in project.priority.all %}{{ priority }}{% endfor %}` instead, which will render all the related priorities. **Note**: forgot the `.all` in the comment previously.

Comment: I'm so terrible at django & I appreciate your help. I'm getting `'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable`

Comment: @GaryHost that is my bad I had reposted that comment see the `.all` part there. Once again to be clear `{% for priority in project.priority.all %}{{ priority }}{% endfor %}`